# How the Stackoverflow store the questions and answers, in html file or database?

Tags: html, stack-overflow

Maybe the question is a little puzzle, let me make it out:this question comes from my practice web project in university to build a questions and answers web. So I want to know how the web like Stackoverflow to store the question and its answers: is stored in a database? Or a question and its follow answers are stored in a single html?

I want stored the post data when php handle the form, storing the html context and image. When it's a question, create a new html named the question title and date, containing the question content. When it's an answer, find the question html and add the answer content into it. Does this plan good or useful?

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server database ....

Answer (score 1):

[Look here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Database SQL Server 2014 CTP2 running Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R1 x64